Dictionary between light propagation in curved spacetime and anisotropic media - with focus on Shapiro delay in weak fields
I am looking for a mathematical dictionary to translate from light propagation in curved spacetime to light propagation in anisotropic media. Special focus is on the optical path length in the context of the Shapiro delay in weak fields. I haven't found any formulation that uses the refraction index tensor for the light travel time.
